# How do I change the response for a HTTP OPTIONS request in a Spring MVC 2.5 application?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc

This sounds like a trivial question but somehow I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a Spring MVC application. I don't support any http methods except GET and POST. I have the following set in all my controllers beans:

```
<property name="supportedMethods" value="GET,POST"/>
```

However, an OPTIONS request sent to my application sends back a response that shows *all* http methods as allowed.

How do I change the OPTIONS response to show only GET and POST methods as allowed? I know I could do this in a servlet by overriding the `doOptions` method, but I am not sure about a Spring MVC application. Do I have to extend the `DispatcherServlet` and override `doOptions`?

The application is using Spring mvc 2.5.6 with SimpleFormController based controllers and xml based config.

Comment: I don't do Spring, so here's just a comment with a link: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=53472 It shows several ways how to control this. You may find it useful as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link, BalusC. The scenario described there is a bit different (controller wrapped servlet vs. a pure controller) but it confirms my doubts: OPTIONS request doesn't go through to the application by default and is handled by DispatcherServlet itself, it seems. So now my question becomes: if the OPTIONS did go through to the controller (per the config change suggested in the link), how do I make it return a 200 with (GET, POST) as opposed to a 405 in response. The poster in the link had to extend the DispatcherServlet and override stuff there. That's what I think I will have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could invoke `WebContentGenerator#setSupportedMethods` which receives as input parameter an array of strings containing supported methods. `WebContentGenerator` is the base class for spring 2.x controllers, so you just need to invoke this method during the construction of your controller that surely extends it. You also could use the Constructor of WebContentGenerator that receives a string varargs (supported methods) as input parameter.

Unfortunately, the `doOptions` method in `FrameworkServlet` class invokes `super.doOptions(request, response);` of `HttpServlet` class. The ouput of this method is based on the declared methods in the servlet, something like this:

```
Method[] methods = getAllDeclaredMethods(this.getClass());

for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    Method m = methods[i];

    if (m.getName().equals("doGet")) {
        ALLOW_GET = true;
        ALLOW_HEAD = true;
    }
    if (m.getName().equals("doPost"))
        ALLOW_POST = true;
    if (m.getName().equals("doPut"))
        ALLOW_PUT = true;
    if (m.getName().equals("doDelete"))
        ALLOW_DELETE = true;
}
```

The DispatcherServlet class (and its base class FrameworkServlet) declares all these methods: `doPut`, `doDelete`, `doGet`, `doPost` etc., so the output of `doOptions` is not what you desire. I think the only way is subclassing the DispatcherServlet.

Comment: That's what I am already doing when I set the property named supportedMethods through the xml config. I am setting the supported methods to just GET and POST. That makes the controllers not support rest of the methods (except OPTIONS). However, that does not change the output of an OPTIONS request for the controller. It still sends a response showing ALL methods enabled. That's what I am trying to find a solution for.

Comment: Well, now I understand your question, I'm sorry. I've updated my answer...but I think you should subclass the DispatcherServlet.

Comment: This is what I had arrived at too after looking at the source codes of the involved classes. Since there is no better way of doing it provided by Spring, I am accepting this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I have not handled OPTIONS messages.

In your request handler (annotated with @Controller) you can use RequestMethod.OPTIONS to handle an Options request.  For example you might use

```
  ... stuff ...  
  @RequestMapping(RequestMethod.OPTIONS)  
  public String processOptions()
  {
  ... stuff ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The application is however using Spring mvc 2.5.6 with SimpleFormController based controllers and xml based config. I am sorry I failed to mention this in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a bit old but I've found additional info on this question that I hope will help others in the future.

The @RequestMapping(RequestMethod.OPTIONS) approach won't work immediately using the DispatcherServlet out of the box since its superclass, FrameworkServlet, first delegates to its superclass, HttpServlet, as noted above which scans the servlet to see if it implements the doXXX methods and sets the Allow header accordingly. But following the call to super.doOptions(...) it then has these lines:

```
if (this.dispatchOptionsRequest) {
     processRequest(request, response);
}
```

And there is a setDispatchOptionsRequest(boolean) that can be used to set the dispatchOptionsRequest value to true. Only then will the DispatcherServlet pass to the controller the OPTIONS request to an appropriately annotated method.

I needed to do this to allow the OPTIONS request to return different values based upon authorizations of the current user. So by subclassing DispatcherServlet and setting that parameter in its default constructor I was finally able to receive the call in my controller for http OPTIONS requests and handle it on my own.

And one more thought, in that controller method you can declare a parameter of type HttpServletResponse and Spring will hand the instance to you. Once had you can call reset() to purge the Allow header already set and roll your own as needed.

(Note: A similar patter is had in FrameworkServlet for http TRACE support via a setDispatchTraceRequest if you plan on getting those requests through to your controller methods annotated with @RequestMapping(RequestMethod.TRACE)).